# How to display a popup dialog box that shows corrections for a word

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I am creating a word correction extension, it wraps the wrong word in a span element. When the user hover over the word a drop down menu of possible correction shall appear. Here is my code it is not working properly, how can align each one in a row currently they appear besides each other.

Also is there a better approach to do this?

```js
$(".error").each(function(index, element) {
      $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
      $(this).mouseover(function() {
        if ($(this).has('.popup-base').length > 0) {
          return;
        }
        var popup = document.createElement('div');
        popup.className = 'popup-base';
        let correctionslist = element.getAttribute('suggestions').split(',');
        for (correct of correctionslist) {
          popup.innerHTML += '<span class="listitem">' + correct + ' </span>';
        }

        $(this).append(popup);

      });
     });
```

```css
.error {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.popup-base {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.error:hover .popup-base {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable><span data-offset-key="6j93r-0-0"><span data-text="true">Por favor, leia as <span class="error" suggestions="reges,regra,regrãs,regres,regras,regrá,regrã,regôs,regre,regas,regro,regos" style="cursor: pointer;">regrs</span>. Meu <span class="error"
    suggestions="nom." style="cursor: pointer;">nom</span> é <span class="error" suggestions="Nícolas,Nicola,Ricolas,Picolas,Ni colas,Nicol as,Nicolaus,Unicolas,Nicolau" style="cursor: pointer;">Nicolas</span>.&nbsp;Brasil é o <span class="error"
    suggestions="unto,quento,quinto,quanto,queto,sunto,quito,quoto,cunto,munto,punto,junto,quinoto,quinteto,quiranto" style="cursor: pointer;">qunto</span> <span class="error" suggestions="mair,amor,moar,maro,mar,mor,maore,maori,maior,mafor,major,mora,maar"
    style="cursor: pointer;">maor</span> pais do mundo.</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `listitem` elements are using `<span>` which is an inline element and why the words display next to each other instead of on top of each other. You can use a different element or add a class to the `listitem` elements to make the `display:block`. In this example, I chose to add CSS for the `listitem` class. I also added a hover effect for fun.

```js
$(".error").each(function(index, element) {
      $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
      $(this).mouseover(function() {
        if ($(this).has('.popup-base').length > 0) {
          return;
        }
        var popup = document.createElement('div');
        popup.className = 'popup-base';
        let correctionslist = element.getAttribute('suggestions').split(',');
        for (correct of correctionslist) {
          popup.innerHTML += '<span class="listitem">' + correct + ' </span>';
        }

        $(this).append(popup);

      });
     });
```

```css
.error {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.popup-base {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.error:hover .popup-base {
  display: block;
}

.listitem {
  display:block;
  margin:7px 0;
}

.listitem:hover {
  background-color:blue;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable><span data-offset-key="6j93r-0-0"><span data-text="true">Por favor, leia as <span class="error" suggestions="reges,regra,regrãs,regres,regras,regrá,regrã,regôs,regre,regas,regro,regos" style="cursor: pointer;">regrs</span>. Meu <span class="error"
    suggestions="nom." style="cursor: pointer;">nom</span> é <span class="error" suggestions="Nícolas,Nicola,Ricolas,Picolas,Ni colas,Nicol as,Nicolaus,Unicolas,Nicolau" style="cursor: pointer;">Nicolas</span>.&nbsp;Brasil é o <span class="error"
    suggestions="unto,quento,quinto,quanto,queto,sunto,quito,quoto,cunto,munto,punto,junto,quinoto,quinteto,quiranto" style="cursor: pointer;">qunto</span> <span class="error" suggestions="mair,amor,moar,maro,mar,mor,maore,maori,maior,mafor,major,mora,maar"
    style="cursor: pointer;">maor</span> pais do mundo.</span>
  </span>
</div>
```